# Python stepwise regression with AIC?

Tags: python, r, regression, model-comparison

what is the Python equivalent for R step() function of stepwise regression with AIC as criteria?

Is there an existing function in statsmodels.api?

Comment: I found a post with [forward-backward selection based on p-value](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/24405/how-to-do-stepwise-regression-using-sklearn/24447#24447?newreg=73e38e7b7b694b7fb595e3f81404da79) but How do I do that with AIC?

Comment: I have something similar on my curve fitting web site, if you post a link to your data I can try it and see what it finds.